# Moved VPS - Setting up nameserver on new machine

Tags: dns, cpanel, vps, whm

I just upgraded to a new VPS with GoDaddy.  My old onw was with them as well.  I setup the DNS on the new machine just like the old one, but with the new IP address.  Is there anything I need to do other than that to get the new DNS information to propagate?  Did it last night at about 10:30, but when I use DNSStuff.com it still shows the old IP.  Do I just need to wait?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague. Are you saying you want to change the hostname of your VPS from the IP of the old VPS to that of the new one?

If so, you need to change the hostname record in the DNS for the hostname's parent domain, wherever that is.

When you say "you setup DNS on the new machine" do you mean you are running a nameserver on it? Is that with the intention of it acting as an authoritative  nameserver for some domains (presumably hosted on that machine?)

If so, you would need to update the nameserver glue record, again within the domain that is the parent to the nameserver hostname.

There are even more possibilities. You have to be a bit more specific I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes I am running a nameserver on the new VPS, as I did on the old one.  I'm sorry I was vague, wasn't sure how to explain.  I setup the account in WHM for the domain that will be NS1 and NS2 on the new machine, which is the same as the old machine, just a different IP.  I just needed to know is there something else I need to do in order for the internet to see the new machine and not the old one.  Sorry if that doesn't make sense.  I know enough to get me in trouble.

Comment: I believe I found what I needed to do, and that was to login to my GoDaddy account and change the domain's hostname IP address.